# firebase.auth().currentUser retorna nulo ao recaregar a pagina

Tags: angular, firebase, auth, angularfire

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com angular2 + angularfire2 + firebase,
estou enfrentando dificuldades em implementar a autenticação, consegui fazer  o login e  o logout, porem quando a pagina é recarregada eu perco a autenticação.

Meu Seriço.

```
import {Injectable, OnChanges, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";


@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

static isLoggedIn: boolean;


constructor(private router: Router, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            LoginService.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
            LoginService.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    });

}

login(email: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((data => {
        LoginService.isLoggedIn = true;

        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    })).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        console.log(error.message);

    });

}

logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}

}
```

Meu Guard:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot,         
Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {LoginService} from '../login/login.service';
import {AngularFireAuth} from "angularfire2/auth";
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor( private router: Router) {
}

canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | 
Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(LoginService.isLoggedIn){
        return true;
    }else{
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Eu dei uma olhada em problemas parecidos com o meu aqui no starckoverflow,
tinham comentado em implementar o  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged porem nao entendi como implementa-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema Resolvido...

Quando carregada perdia a autenticação, mas quando navega para outra rota ela voltava, não sei porque acontecia isso, mas para resolver meu problema acabei usando [localStorange](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage), agora quando eu logo no sistema eu salvo uma variável e ela é verifica se existe, e quando eu faço logof eu apago minha variável.